# Excel Interop Worksheets list has extra sheets, UsedRange has no data

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I'm using the Excel Office Interop from C#. (In VS 2013). I'm working with an Excel workbook that was created in the version of Excel that came with Office 2010 Professional Plus. The workbook has an .xlsx extension.

When I open the workbook in Excel, it has 4 sheets visible, but when I open it using the interop, the Worksheets collection contains sheets with a bunch of other names, like these:

```
Icons 
International URLs 
International Settings 
DropdownSizer
International Translastions 
Data Validation 
International Data
```

Then after that list, the sheets that are visible in the tabs of the workbook finally appear. But when I try to get at the UsedRange for any of the sheets, it has no data in it.

My code works fine for other workbooks created from the same Office/Excel installation, which only have single sheets.

Here are some mashed together snippets from my code with comments, null checks, debugging code, etc. stripped out:

```
private Excel.Application xlApp;
private Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
private Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet;
public Excel.Range usedRange;   

public void Open(string pathname, int sheetNum = 1) {
    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathname, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);        
    xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(sheetNum);
    usedRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
}

public string[] GetSheetNames() {
    var sheetNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet worksheet in xlApp.Worksheets) {
        sheetNames.Add(worksheet.Name);
    }
    return sheetNames.ToArray();
}

public void SetCurrentSheet(int sheetNum) {
    usedRange = xlWorkbook.Worksheets[sheetNum].UsedRange;
}
```

I've tried using the xlWorkbook.Worksheets instead of xlApp.Worksheets. No difference.

How can I get just the sheets that show up in the tabs when I open the workbook in Excel?

After doing that, how can I get at the data in each sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to filter your `sheetNames` list to only include visible sheets, you can try the following:

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet worksheet in xlApp.Worksheets)
{
    if (worksheet.Visible == XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible) 
    {
        sheetNames.Add(worksheet.Name);
    }
}
```

> I've tried using the xlWorkbook.Worksheets instead of
>   xlApp.Worksheets. No difference.

The documentation says that the `Application.Worksheets` property returns a collection of all the worksheets in the active workbook. Since the currently active workbook is the same object as the one referenced by your `xlWorkbook` variable, there can't be any difference.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly for filtering out those other extraneous sheets, whatever those are. But I'm still getting no data when I examine the worksheet.UsedRange, even though there is data in that sheet when I open the workbook in Excel.

Comment: If you add `var usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange` as a second statement inside the `if` clause, what do you get? Does it return `null`?

Comment: That's interesting, I do get the range that way. So there's something wrong with the way I'm retrieving the usedRange.